# Pymatching: 'Matching' object has no attribute 'decode_batch'

Tags: toric-code, pymatching

I am trying to run the example from documentation: [pymatching docs](https://pymatching.readthedocs.io/en/latest/toric-code-example.html)

Here is my code:

```
from pymatching import Matching
H = toric_code_x_stabilisers(3)
logicals = toric_code_x_logicals(3)
print("logicals :",logicals)
p=0.04
matching=Matching(H)
print("Matching :",matching)
noise = np.random.binomial(1, p, H.shape[1])
print("noise :",noise)
syndrome = H@noise % 2
print("syndrome :", syndrome)
prediction = matching.decode(syndrome)
print("prediction :", prediction)
predicted_logicals_flipped = logicals@prediction % 2
print("predicted_logicals_flipped :", predicted_logicals_flipped)
actual_logicals_flipped = logicals@noise % 2
print("actual_logicals_flipped :", actual_logicals_flipped)



def num_decoding_failures_vectorised(H, logicals, error_probability, num_shots):
    matching = Matching.from_check_matrix(H, weights=np.log((1-p)/p), faults_matrix=logicals)
    noise = (np.random.random((num_shots, H.shape[1])) < error_probability).astype(np.uint8)
    shots = (noise @ H.T) % 2
    actual_observables = (noise @ logicals.T) % 2
    predicted_observables = matching.decode_batch(shots)
    num_errors = np.sum(np.any(predicted_observables != actual_observables, axis=1))
    return num_errors
    
result = num_decoding_failures_vectorised(H,logicals,p,100)
print(results)
```

where `toric_code_x_stabilisers` and `toric_code_x_logicals` directly taken from the following page: [toric code](https://pymatching.readthedocs.io/en/latest/toric-code-example.html)

However, I am having the error: "AttributeError: 'Matching' object has no attribute 'decode_batch'"
I am assuming the code should be correct since it is taken from the documentation and I do not know what causes to this error.

Any help regarding this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're on the latest version. `pip install --upgrade pymatching`.

Comment: I thought I am using the new version but you were right, it was the previous version. probably the new version was in the other pc ... Sorry about this problem